Find second order aggregations in polars
Say I have a dataframe:
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'b':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,18,17]})
print(df)
output:
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 10  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 11  │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 12  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 13  │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 14  │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 15  │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 18  │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 17  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

Now, within each group according to a, I want to find the max of the last values according to the second level groups in b
something that gets achieved by the following code
df.with_columns(pl.col("c").last().over(["a", "b"])).group_by(pl.col("a")).agg(pl.col("c").max())
output:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 18  │
│ 1   ┆ 13  │
└─────┴─────┘

Is there a way to do this with one expression? Currently I would have to write a separate class for such cases that provides one expression to go to the with_columns and another expression for the group_by. I can do that but I am also trying to be better at polars and would like to know if it can be done with just one expression

I think you're asking for chained over calls: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14361
pl.col("c").last().over("a", "b").max().over("a")
# InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation

It is "possible" to wrap complex functionality as a "single expression" using map_batches
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct("a", "c").last().over("a", "b").map_batches(lambda s:
        s.struct.unnest()
         .select(pl.col("c").max().over("a"))
         .to_series()
    )
    .alias("result")
)

shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ result │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 13     │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 11  ┆ 13     │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 12  ┆ 13     │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 13  ┆ 13     │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 14  ┆ 18     │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 15  ┆ 18     │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 18  ┆ 18     │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 17  ┆ 18     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘

But to make that reusable is probably rather tricky.

You can use .unique to get the last observed value within the 'a', 'b' groupings. Then use a group_by.agg(col('c').max()) to get the maximum from this result:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'b':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,18,17],
})

print(
    df.unique(['a', 'b'], keep='last')
    .group_by('a').agg(pl.col('c').max())
)
# shape: (2, 2)
# ┌─────┬─────┐
# │ a   ┆ c   │
# │ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 13  │
# │ 2   ┆ 18  │
# └─────┴─────┘


Well logically I don't think you even need to use with_columns().
As you only need values returned by Expr.last() (you can also use GroupBy.last in your case) within a,b  to calculate Expr.max(), I'd say you just need to perform DataFrame.group_by() twice, each time cutting down the size of the DataFrame:
(
    df
    .group_by("a","b").last()
    .group_by("a").agg(pl.col("c").max())
)

┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 18  │
│ 1   ┆ 13  │
└─────┴─────┘

This is, of course, not one expression, but I think it's clear enough it's a proper flow of groupings for your task.
You could probably use GroupBy.map_groups() if you really want to run it as single operation:
(
    df
    .group_by("a")
    .map_groups(lambda g: g.group_by("b").last().max())
    .drop("b")
)

┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 13  │
│ 2   ┆ 18  │
└─────┴─────┘

